# Como puedo crear un auto completado en un TextArea JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy tratando de crear un Auto-Completado `JavaFX`, pero que el Auto-Completado esta en un `TextArea`, pero no consigo la forma de hacerlo. Sin embargo, e visto la manera de hacer un Auto-Completado en un `TextField` pero no es lo que necesito, ya que lo que deseo hacer, es que esta función este en un `Textarea` como los que usan los editores de texto actuales.

Comment: no has considerado usar AutoComplete de  ControlsFX? or implementar este ejemplo https://gist.github.com/floralvikings/10290131

Comment: si amigo pero el AutoComplete de ControlsFX solo se puede usar en un TextField hasta donde tengo en tendido no se puede usar en un TextArea si sabes como aplicarlo a un TextArea me enseñas por favor

Comment: no cuentas con nada creado? edita tu pregunta y comparte el codigo que has creado hasta este momento asi podria ayudarte mejor

Comment: disculpa amigo lo que sucede es que no tengo nada del código creado en si solo el textArea  lo que necesito es que cuando yo presione la tecla "a" en el TextArea me muestre todas las palabras que se encuentran agregada por la letra "a" como una especie de diccionario que me va a mostrar en un textarea las palabras que hayan dentro de las letras en este acaso seria "a" ejemplo si presiono la tecla a y tengo guardada la palabra avion que cuando presione la tecla "a" me muestre la palabra avión en un menu la seleccione y agregue al textarea que eso seria los auto completados

Comment: que tienen los editores de texto como sublime text3

Comment: nesecito un auto completado como este pero que no sea en el textfield si no en un textarea https://www.google.com/search?q=autocomplete+in+textarea+javafx&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvqofnxZXcAhXlt1kKHW5GBUwQ_AUICygC&biw=1440&bih=771&dpr=1#imgrc=GJ97anajO3QvIM:

Comment: Te recomiendo poner el código de algo que estés haciendo, a ver que estas haciendo mal, de esa forma, te podrán ayudar mejor.

Comment: Lo se amigo lo que sucede es que no encuentro la forma de agregar o colocarle la autocompletacion a un textarea así que por eso no muestro el código por que no lo tengo